# replace '.' with ';' in a string except 3rd and 6th

Tags: javascript

I want to replace `.` with `;` in `"qwe.qwee.qwer.qwer.qwer.qwww.qwww"` except 3rd and 4th `'.'` with the help of `for` loops and `if` statements.

Can anyone update this with an `if` statement?

```
var str = "qww.qwer.qwer.qwer.qwww.qwww.qwww";
for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
  str = str.replace(".", ";");
}
console.log(str);
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why specifically on the 3rd and 4th (or 6th) occurrence? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = 'qwe.qwee.qwer.qwer.qwer.qwww.qwww';
var out = a.split('.').map(function(s, i) { 
    return s + (i >= 2 && i <= 3 ? '' : ';') 
}).join('');
console.log( out );
```